# Azure create multiple VMs in parallel fails

Tags: java, azure

I am using this sample
https://github.com/azure-samples/compute-java-manage-virtual-machines-in-parallel

It works fine with VM number 5.
However, specifying number of VMs 17 or 33 it fails with the number of exceptions equal to number of VMs that were failed to be created (some of them are created). No good error message is returned. What may be the error?

I am getting log like this

```
[RxIoScheduler-22] INFO com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.VirtualMachines createOrUpdate - <-- 409 Conflict https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/rgcoppc3834913a3950/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VM-19?api-version=2016-04-30-preview (1815 ms, 195-byte body)
[RxIoScheduler-21] INFO com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.VirtualMachines createOrUpdate - <-- 409 Conflict https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/rgcoppc3834913a3950/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VM-30?api-version=2016-04-30-preview (1893 ms, 195-byte body)
[RxIoScheduler-6] INFO com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.VirtualMachines createOrUpdate - <-- 409 Conflict https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/..../resourceGroups/rgcoppc3834913a3950/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VM-10?api-version=2016-04-30-preview (2096 ms, 195-byte body)
```

Stacktrace example (33 VMs, some not created):

```
31 exceptions occurred. 
rx.exceptions.CompositeException: 31 exceptions occurred. 
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.reportError(OperatorMerge.java:268)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:658)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:568)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:857)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:656)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:568)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:281)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMapNotification$MapNotificationSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMapNotification.java:155)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMapNotification$MapNotificationSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMapNotification.java:121)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:70)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.onCompleted(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:68)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:656)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:568)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:281)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeMap.java:97)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:656)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:568)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:857)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeMap.java:97)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeMap.java:97)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:656)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:568)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:857)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeMap.java:97)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:656)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:568)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:281)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeMap.java:97)
    at rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(SingleProducer.java:75)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSingle$ParentSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorSingle.java:110)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTake$1.onNext(OperatorTake.java:80)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeFilter.java:76)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:395)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:355)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:846)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:511)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:466)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:244)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:148)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:511)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:466)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:244)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:148)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:173)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:248)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:148)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$2$1.onNext(OnSubscribeRedo.java:244)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$ScalarAsyncProducer.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:200)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$2$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:114)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:230)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  ComposedException 1 :
    com.microsoft.azure.CloudException
        at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient.createExceptionFromResponse(AzureClient.java:591)
        at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient.access$000(AzureClient.java:34)
        at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient$1.call(AzureClient.java:135)
        at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient$1.call(AzureClient.java:132)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:173)
        at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:248)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:148)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77)
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276)
        at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
```

Answer (score 0):

Java Azure SDK should be more helpful at providing meaningful error messages.

In Web Azure interface go to "Events" page. There you will find failure logs.
Messages there are still not very helpful but then Google for them.

I found that every region and/or subscription has quotas
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits

Here are typical errors:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors#quotaexceeded

You should issue support request to increase quota:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/girishp/2015/09/20/increasing-core-quota-limits-in-azure/